# PHP - Page is blocked when large files are being downloaded

Tags: php, asynchronous, download

I have a download.php page which will be invoked everytime a user clicks "Download" button on my page. The file is around 1 GB. However, the current page got blocked before the file is completely downloaded. Is there a way I can make this an async task so that the user can still use the website while the file is being downloaded to his computer.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by blocked?

Comment: Why don't you just give a link to the file? If pressed it should start downloading...

Comment: @Naruto block means if I click on other button on the page, it will not respond

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sessions, then before you begin any long running process you should call [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) or you will get blocking site-wide.  From the docs there:

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time.

So, if you have a long running script that called `session_start()` and did not call `session_write_close()` then the result is, any page that needs to access a session now has to wait for the long running script to finish execution before it can begin. Thus, site-wide blocking.

This may or may not solve your issue, because I'm not sure what you mean by "blocking" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First Create your download links like this :-

```
<a class="download" href="/myfiles/video/file.pdf"> Dow
```

nload file.pdf

then in Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('.download', 'click', function(){

       var href = $(this).href;
       $('<iframe />', { src :  href }).appendTo('body');    
       return false; // prevent from default action, can be done with e.preventDefault() also

   }) // __download

}); // __ document ready
```

This technique use by many big sites like facebook, github etc, and it will not block current page, everything will be working like before but browser will show file save dialog to download file, I did not test this code so there may be some syntex error,  Thanks :)